# Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

Tags: reactjs, npm, bootstrap-4, import

Installed bootstrap via npm on my react project
Importing bootstrap
`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

but it outputs an error: `Cannot find module 'D:\project\my-app\node_modules\schema-utils\src\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try deleting `package-lock.json` and run `npm install`

Verify that in your `package.json` file there is an entry for `main`, usually something like `"main": "dist/cjs"`

Comment: and if no main present, how to create a proper one?

Answer (score 5):

I had to delete both my `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`, then
run `npm i`. (this was in my react app)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use "npm update --force" which resolves my issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `yarn` try deleting `yarn.lock` and run `yarn` again.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on our Jenkins server. The solution was to run the job once with `yarn cache clean`. After the job completed we removed that line and everything was happy again.

Answer (score -1):

I went for another approach. As deleting `package-lock.json` & running `npm install` didn't work for me, I deleted my project and created another one with `npx create-react-app my-react-activities`.

Once the project was created, I `cd` into it and ran `npm start`.

I can't tell you why it worked, but it runs well. If anyone has an explanation for it, I would gladly read it.